# iOS-Segmented control in navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm looking for a way to add a segmented control to my navigation bar, but I still want the title and bar buttons to be there.

Like the purchased section in the app store:

[image: segmented control in nav bar]

I have tried adding a bar segmented control to my navigation item, then using the prompt instead of the title, but the prompt does not have bold text. Could I make the text bold and still have bar buttons too?

Comment: Anyone have some ideas?

Comment: I could really use some help here...

Answer (score 0):

I know you probably found another way, and that my answer may sound cheap, but here's what I did. I just added a view underneath my navigation bar with the proper constraints, and put my segmented control there. It works good for my application and looks pretty much like that picture.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

give you the dirty example I made

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 60)];
view.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xffffff);
[self.view addSubview:view];
UIView *bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 124, 320, 1)];
bottomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:bottomView];
UISegmentedControl *sg = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"one", @"two"]];
sg.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 40);
[view addSubview:sg];


for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
    for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
        [subView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]];
        subView.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

the screenshot
[image: sample]

hope this can enlighten you to achieve what you want

Comment: @Jacob Yes it's just another view. just set it translucent